# Why an API Service hosted in a Windows Server becomes unavailable for a while and reset itself randomly after some time?

Tags: c#, php, api, http, plesk

A C# .NET6 WebAPI service is hosted in a Windows Server. This has some CronJobs written in PHP (running on Plesk) to be executed to save/update products to a WooCommerce site.

**Process description:**

- CronJob executed every 10 mins (PHP script on Plesk) because the job has runtime limit of 600s (10 mins)
- Runs for hours continuously to save/update 2000+ products in a WooCommerce site.

**Expected scenario:**

- API service runs continuously without stopping and CronJob triggers API endpoint every 10 mins daily to fullfill the above mentioned process.

**Current scenario:**

- API service stops randomly which cause the CronJob to not continue the process.

[Screenshot of HTTP response from Swagger API endpoint when it's unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJrHU.png)

**When running/testing the service locally it all works fine.**

Anyone please explain or provide insights on this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 is "Internal Server Error". It is a choice by the server to send 500 in response to some internal error (hence the name). Have you checked the CloudFlare report for more information? Perhaps look up the logs with the CF ray id (in the response). Is it different if you bypass CF and just access the API directly? Perhaps CF is blocking your requests because you make too many/it thinks you're suspicious. Who knows.

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion @ProgrammingLlama. Can you please tell 'Whether disabling the security on CF settings for now will let us run the API service or not?'

Comment: Let me consult my crystal ball.... You need to get to the root of where the Internal Server Error is coming from. This requires investigation on your part, not Internet strangers with no access to your systems telling you what the cause is (we can't because we don't know).